# Maximum Height of a Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Hi I came across a code to find the maximum height of a binary tree.
In this code why is there a `+1` in the return statement?

```
public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
          return 0;
        }
        return Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right)) + 1;
    }
```

Comment: To accumulate the depth value as the recursive logic goes down until the leaves of the tree

Comment: A node have two sub-tree, left and right.  The height of a node is the height of left or right, whichever is higher, plus the node itself, hence +1.  It should be quite straight-forward.  For example, there is a node.  Its left tree is of height 10, right tree is of height 7.  Then the height of the node itself is 10 plus 1 more level for itself, which gives 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there wasn't, the result would always be 0.

The max height of a binary tree is the max height of the child having a larger max height (that's the `Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right))` part) + 1 for the root of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a tree consisting of a single root node.  Then the following return statement would return 1, which is what we expect:

```
return Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right)) + 1;
return Math.max(0, 0) + 1;
return 1;
```

As your base case shows, an empty tree would have a height of zero, and you can build up to taller trees' height using induction.